# Which CSS parameters have p:commandButton?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have h:commandButton and I want, that It look like Primefaces button. I added

```
styleClass="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only ui-state-hover"
```

but it's not full list. When I click to button, style is not changing. Button is not alive. What parameters I forgot to add?

Comment: Please post your facelets code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most important style classes used to tune PF components are covered in PrimeFaces User's guide. But I think that exact CSS class names could be version-dependent. The best way to know it would be to open the generated HTML code in  webbrowser's development tools and view the resulting markup.

The last but not the least would be to mention that JSF generates *pure form elements* while PF usually generates *wrappers around form elements*, so that user interacts with, for example plain `div`, and not with `input`. But that'd also be answerable pretty soon as you open browser's tools.